# Is it possible to upcast to a trait when destructuring enums?

Tags: enums, rust, traits, upcasting

I'd like to be able to destructure/upcast enum variants to a commonly implemented trait.  Here's the setup:

```
trait SomeTrait {
    fn some_func(&self);
}

struct SomeStruct1;
impl SomeTrait for SomeStruct1 {
    fn some_func(&self) {}
}

struct SomeStruct2;
impl SomeTrait for SomeStruct2 {
    fn some_func(&self) {}
}

enum SomeEnum {
    Value1(SomeStruct1),
    Value2(SomeStruct2),
}
```

Here's one possibility I tried:

```
fn call_some_func(some_enum: SomeEnum) {
    match some_enum {
        SomeEnum::Value1(ref some_trait: &SomeTrait) |
        SomeEnum::Value2(ref some_trait: &SomeTrait) => some_trait.some_func()
    }
}
```

It resulted in this error:

```
error: expected one of `)`, `,`, or `@`, found `:`
  --> src/main.rs:22:40
   |
22 |         SomeEnum::Value1(ref some_trait: &SomeTrait) |
   |                                        ^ expected one of `)`, `,`, or `@` here
```

This was another idea I had:

```
fn call_some_func2(some_enum: SomeEnum) {
    match some_enum {
        _(ref some_trait: &SomeTrait) => some_trait.some_func()
    }
}
```

Which also failed:

```
error: expected one of `=>`, `if`, or `|`, found `(`
  --> src/main.rs:22:10
   |
22 |         _(ref some_trait: &SomeTrait) => some_trait.some_func()
   |          ^ expected one of `=>`, `if`, or `|` her
```

Does anyone know of a way to accomplish this type of destructuring?

Comment: Will every case of the enum contain something that implements the trait, like you've shown here, or will there be some cases which don't?

Comment: For my current usage, yes they all implement the trait.  I wouldn't be opposed to a solution that allowed pattern matching so that wasn't a requirement though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you cannot *while* destructuring. You can do it *after* though:

```
// My preferred
fn call_some_func(some_enum: SomeEnum) {
    let x: &SomeTrait = match some_enum {
        SomeEnum::Value1(ref x) => x,
        SomeEnum::Value2(ref x) => x,
    };
    x.some_func();
}
```

```
// Also works
fn call_some_func(some_enum: SomeEnum) {
    let x = match some_enum {
        SomeEnum::Value1(ref x) => x as &SomeTrait,
        SomeEnum::Value2(ref x) => x,
    };
    x.some_func();
}
```

I'd encourage you to extract this to a method for reuse:

```
impl SomeEnum {
    fn as_trait(&self) -> &SomeTrait {
        match *self {
            SomeEnum::Value1(ref x) => x,
            SomeEnum::Value2(ref x) => x,
        }
    }
}

fn call_some_func(some_enum: SomeEnum) {
    some_enum.as_trait().some_func();
}
```

And probably to implement the trait on the enum itself, if all the variants implement it. This way, consumers don't have to care:

```
impl SomeTrait for SomeEnum {
    fn some_func(&self) {
        self.as_trait().some_func()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  It feels like unfortunate boilerplate, but encapsulates it nicely.